# se queda en ciclo infinito y no logro ver por que

Tags: c++, while

Este es el código:

```
while (op != 0) {
    op = 0;
    scanf_s("%i", &op);
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n");


    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        printf("Ingrese el numero de cedula del cliente y presione enter: \n");
        scanf_s("%i", &numCedula);
        if (numCedula <= 99999999 && numCedula > 0) {
            invertirNumero(numCedula);
            resultDigito = sumaDigitos(numCedula);
            printf("La suma de los digitos es: %i \n", resultDigito);
            i++;
            arreglo[i] = resultDigito;
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("el numero de cedula no puede exceder los 8 digitos \n tiene que ser positivo \n distinto de cero \n y no puede contener letras ni puntos");
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        ordenar(arreglo);
        break;

    }
    if (op) {
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

creo q es algo relacionado en el scan que esta luego del while el ciclo imprime en pantalla y luego queda en bucle infinito, el problema principal esta cuando la opcion escogida es 1 y el scanf_S de numCedula toma un valor que no sea un integer

Comment: Hola Gaedi. ¿Cuáles son tus hipótesis? ¿Qué probaste para corregirlo? Como comprenderás, no podemos ir línea a línea revisando tu código si no pones de tu parte. Lee [ask] y luego dale a [edit] explicando tu proceso.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que estás trabajando con [tag:c++]?

Answer (score 0):

> el problema principal esta cuando la opcion escogida es 1 y el scanf_S de numCedula toma un valor que no sea un integer

Si se produce un error de lectura (p.ej: intentar leer una cadena como entero), los caracteres erróneos no se sacan del buffer de entrada... si no limpias el buffer el resto de lecturas podrán ser igualmente incorrectas y el programa puede acabar, como es tu caso, con un bucle infinito.

Para empezar las funciones de la famila `scanf` devuelven un entero que indica el número de valores leídos. Si en una instrucción tipo:

```
scanf_s("%i", &numCedula);
```

El usuario introduce un texto la función retornará 0.

Lo que tienes que hacer es detectar esa situación y actuar en consecuencia (por ejemplo limpiando el buffer de entrada). ¿Y cómo se limpia el buffer de entrada? Bueno, no hay una forma estándar, pero si asumimos que cuando `scanf` retorna 0 es que el buffer contiene al menos un caracter lo que podemos hacer es descartar caracteres hasta que encontremos un salto de línea:

```
if( scanf_s("%i", &numCedula) == 0 )
{
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Como he dicho no hay un mecanismo estándar para hacer esto y si rediriges la entrada estándar puedes tener problemas, pero con entradas del teclado este mecanismo debería funcionar como norma general.

Por cierto, he hablado todo el rato de C porque aunque el código que expones compila en C++ realmente no tiene nada propio de C++. En C++ lo lógico sería trabajar con `std::cin` y `std::cout` para trabajar con la I/O estándar. En ese caso el código debería lucir así:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cin
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits

if( !std::cin >> numCedula )
{
  // Error
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n'); // Descartar caracteres
  std::cin.clear(); // limpiar flags de error
}
```